# Python view sent TCP packets with POST?

Tags: python

I'm making a `POST` request for file uploading to my server with the following instruction:

```
requests.post(url = 'https://foo/upload/', files=files)
```

If I upload a file multiple times, the first upload takes a long time and the rest are pretty faster.

I would like to analyze each packet in the request and its latency with Python so that I can figure out if the delay comes from the first packet or with every packet of the first request.

For `GET` requests I was doing the following:

```py
r = requests.get(path)
for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
  # Get packet info
r.close()
```

How can I analyze each packet in the POST request?

Comment: Not with a high-level framework like Requests. You're better off using Wireshark next to your app.

Comment: Also, `r.iter_content()` doesn't map in any direct way to the underlying TCP packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packet capture and analysis, I would usually use a tool like Wireshark.

If you want to do it using Python, then it would be possible to use [`RawPcapReader`](https://vnetman.github.io/pcap/python/pyshark/scapy/libpcap/2018/10/25/analyzing-packet-captures-with-python-part-1.html) to analyze packets.